# Java giving "Could not successfully run git" when trying to compile BuildTools jar

Tags: java, linux, git

I am trying to install BuildTools 1.18 with Java 18 in linux, following [this](https://www.spigotmc.org/wiki/buildtools/) tutorial. When I try to compile with `java -jar BuildTools.jar --rev latest` as instructed, it gives me this error:

```sh
Could not successfully run git. Please ensure it is installed and functioning. Cannot run program "git" (in directory "."): error=2, No such file or directory
```

Here is the full output (before the error):

```sh
Loading BuildTools version: git-BuildTools-1fbeb7f-147 (#147)
Java Version: Java 18
Current Path: /home/jackpy/spigot/.
```

I have git configured and tried running `git init`, but that didn't change anything.
Why is this happening and how do I fix it?
I am using Debian 10.

Comment: Fedora 35 example: `# dnf install git java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel` ..... and `$ java -jar BuildTools.jar --rev latest` : Success .... `spigot-1.18.2.jar` was built and saved → log.txt → https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sz-LJ173LiWJRDBNkXphkYzqz59RALWK/view?usp=sharing .......... Please add OS name, version to your question.

Comment: I am using Debian 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out. I was using the OpenJDK snap instead of the APT package. I installed the APT package, and it worked.